# Waves 8 or 9 of the UK Household Longitudinal Study

Tags: word-meaning

Could you see what the word "Wave" mean in the title "Waves 8 or 9 of the UK Household Longitudinal Study"?  Google search repeatedly comes back to the similarly titles and I have had no clue what it means. Perhaps one action is called one wave. I am not sure.

> In this secondary analysis of a national, longitudinal cohort study, households that took part in **Waves 8 or 9 of the UK Household Longitudinal Study** (UKHLS) panel, including all members aged 16 or older in April, 2020, were invited to complete the COVID-19 web survey on April 23–30, 2020. Participants who were unable to make an informed decision as a result of incapacity, or who had unknown postal addresses or addresses abroad were excluded.

> Source:  [Mental health before and during the COVID-19 pandemic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2215036620303084#:%7E:text=In%20this%20secondary%20analysis%20of%20a%20national%2C%20longitudinal,unknown%20postal%20addresses%20or%20addresses%20abroad%20were%20excluded.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to separate sections in a longitudinal study. I think the word "tranche" may be used in such studies too.
[Sage.pub "wave"](https://methods.sagepub.com/reference/encyclopedia-of-survey-research-methods/n630.xml)

> Within the context of survey research, a **wave** refers to each separate survey in a series of related surveys. If a survey is conducted only once, then the concept of a "wave" does not apply. It is when a survey is conducted two or more times, for example, once a year for 5 years in a row, that each repeated survey is called a wave.

[emphasis added]

Comment: Just before me. I had trouble finding an appropriate dictionary definition, but [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wave) has *11 countable noun. A wave is a large number of people moving somewhere at the same time. The rising violence sent a wave of refugees across the border. Their commander ordered them forward in waves.* So **wave** is used here as one of a series of tests.